# Vue + Vite project build is blank

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, vercel

My Vue + Vite project build is blank this is the folder structure:
[image: folder structure]
and my index.vue is in src/pages, the index.html is blank with zero code in it, but in npm run dev everything seems to work.

this is my vite.config.js:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  base: './', // added
})
```

I've tried various solutions in stackoverflow, etc none seem to work.

Comment: How are you checking you index file

Comment: How are you building the project?

Comment: Through Vercel, the project builds in vercel with no issues but the website shows nothing it is just blank, and the project has a tech stack of vue+vite+nuxt.